# C# settings hidden for user

Tags: c#, configuration-files, hidden, settings

I want to get and set some application settings hidden for the user. In this case these are two tokens and two tokens that are being altered by the application. But still all four them are a secret to the application user.

I found two ways on MSDN and this forum.

- Use a .config file. -> this sounds okay and I can change some values in it. But I see still a plain text file after publish.
- Use the settings in the project properties. -> should it be? I read warnings about that this not so secure after all.

A lot of sites describe a web server solution while I just want to have a desktop solution.

Btw. It is not a commercial product, I am making a hobby project to learn more from C#.net.

Comment: encrypt the "hidden" settings but still save them to a config file?

Comment: may be encryption will be the way but still almost every thing can be reverse engineered.

Comment: The 'settings' are placed in the config. You only have 1 option here.

Answer (score 2):

If these files need to be altered by the application, you will need to persist these outside of the application so that the new settings will be loaded next time the app starts.

For this, you can always create a config (or settings) file and hide it in the `System.IO.IsolatedStorage` files for the assembly. This is still editable by the user, but its a bit of a pain to find - plus this will transfer over with roaming profiles so that the settings are used cross machine.

Something simple to help you start out:

```
IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly();

string subdirectory = "SomeDirectory";
storage.CreateFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(subdirectory, "settings.config"));
```

Comment: MSDN writes this about IsolatedStorage

"Do not use isolated storage to store high-value secrets, such as unencrypted keys or passwords, because isolated storage is not protected from highly trusted code, from unmanaged code, or from trusted users of the computer."

I've got a feeling that MS can not guarantee a secure way to store a secret setting. .NET and Java always have the problem that is ´easier´ to decompile then something like C++.

IsolatedStorage should be the best way to keep these tokens secret.

Answer (score 1):

Does the * existence* of the setting need to be kept secret, or just its value?

If the latter, I'd suggest encrypting the value you save to the .config file.

Comment: Then I have to store the password somewhere.
I was more hoping on something configurable that is assembled into the code that the user can not access.

Comment: Your user can decompile your dll regardless of where you put the config. Tell us more about your use-case? Why does the setting need to be "hidden"? What you're asking for is basically an area that your program has permission to access, but the user whose rights your program is running over does not have permission to access. Can you see how that might be a problem?

Comment: In this case it is the consumertoken from OAuth. But that is just this case. I want to explore the possibilities of C#. Off course is data compiled into a binary or library reversible when you have the tools and skills. What I want is to make it hard as possible for a user to do this. And for now I find only that it is not 100% safe and that is correct when you store data local, and especially with managed languages as C#. But what is 99% safe, and what 50% etc. I don't find the MSDN site not very crystal about this. Is .config that more unsafe than a project setting?

Comment: You have a variety of ways to do this, but as stated everywhere nothing is 100% safe. If you don't want to store encryption keys in managed assemblies, you can create a c++ or other dll to do the encryption\decryption for you (not impossible, but slightly harder to crack). Other ways you could do this is to make it impossible for the user to modify the values directly by storing them on a web server somewhere (or a location otherwise inaccessible to the *user*) and using a web service to read these. In this case you could even create a challenge\response so that you aren't storing a *password*